# Test browser locale using selenium webdriver

Tags: localization, selenium-rc

I'm trying to test our website with different accept-language headers.  So if accept-language header is fr it shows "bonjour" and if the accept-language header is "en" it shows "hello".

I'm doing this with selenium webdriver, however after a couple of hours of web searching I can't see a way to do it.

I came across this post which suggests that it's not possible (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141) but surely this is something that someone else has needed to do?  Any idea anyone?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://blog.dynatrace.com/2009/08/04/get-more-out-of-functional-web-testing-how-to-correlate-test-reports-with-server-side-log-information/ it describes using fiddler as a proxy for changing request headers.